# why use openSession() in hibernate batch processing

Tags: java, hibernate, batch-processing

Here is the code example from Hibernate about batch processing:

```
Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();

for ( int i=0; i<100000; i++ ) {
    Customer customer = new Customer(.....);
    session.save(customer);
    if ( i % 20 == 0 ) { //20, same as the JDBC batch size
        //flush a batch of inserts and release memory:
        session.flush();
        session.clear();
    }
}

tx.commit();
session.close();
```

At the beginning of codes, it uses `openSession()`.However, when i wrote my code, i use `getCurreentSession()`. It seems like it will generate `org.hibernate.TransactionException: nested transactions not supported` error.

Could anybody explain why this happens?

Answer (score 0):

SessionFactory.openSession() always opens a new session that you have to close once you are done with the operations. SessionFactory.getCurrentSession() returns a session bound to a context - you don't need to close this.

Comment: Thanks for replying. My main question is that why it will generate the error when i use getCurrentSession(). Is it caused by other transactions hold by the session somewhere else as the session is bound to a context? BTW, once i changed getCurrentSession to openSession, the code works fine.